# session value is not geting any data from database when use in sql command

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

i am working on update registration page of student. i had a session variable which is getting currently sign in student. i want to use this session variable to get the current student registration. Session variable values is getting fine but when i use it in SQL query to get data the result is return empty.

```
 <div class="col-md-12 contact-grid agileinfo-5">
                 <asp:GridView ID="GridView" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
                         OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
                          runat="server" CssClass="mydatagrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
                         HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" AllowPaging="True" >
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["UniId"] != null)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Dstring))
                {
                    String query = "SELECT * FROM [TransportManagementSystem].[dbo].[StudentRegistration] where [UniID] =@uniId";
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniId",Session["UniId"].ToString());
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        GridView.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

i am try to bind data to grid view. i am getting no result. help me out here.

Comment: Have you mean `Session["UniId"].ToString()` returns `String.Empty` instead of certain string? In which part of code `Session["UniId"]` has assigned to?

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint somewhere to see if the value of the parameter is set? What is the data type of UniID?

Comment: The question is a little unclear are you saying the Session["UniId"] is empty or that no data is returned from the Sql select statement. If the former please post the code where Session["UniId"] is assigned. If the latter then you will need to check the select statement on your database.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto session["UniId"].ToString return correct value but sql query is not binding data to gridview

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel object{String} is datatype

Comment: Try to use a SqlDataReader instead of a SqlDataAdapter

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel thanks buddy using SqlDataReader works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using SqlDataReader is works for me. thanks everyone for their time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query is not executing to the database so it returns nothing. So first you need to execute against a SQL Server database.

Try to change your code from:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniId",Session["UniId"].ToString());
```

To:

```
Sqlcommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
cmd.Parameter.add("@uniId",Session["UniId"].ToString());
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

**Updated answer**

Maybe you need to populate first the SQLDataAdapter into DataSet?
[For more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter)

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
     cmd.Parameter.add("@uniId",Session["UniId"].ToString());

     DataSet ds = new DataSet();

     using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
     {
          da.Fill(ds);
     }

     if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
     {
          dt = ds.Tables[0];
     }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
query = query.Replace("@uniId", "'" + Session["UniId"].ToString() + "'");
```

Remove this

```
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniId",Session["UniId"].ToString());
```